# How to identify the browser in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

Is it possible to identify the end user's browser in Flash Builder? I have detected a printing problem in Chrome and want to send a warning to Chrome users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific API built into Flash to access that information, but you can pass the information down via [FlashVars](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) or by using [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to ask the browser for it.

Using the latter you could simply say:

```
var userAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call('window.navigator.userAgent.toString');
```

Letting you detect Chrome like:

```
if (userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy , dont worry about it , The answer from above user will be a problem if the customer or end user uses a Browser other than any other Known Browsers

So if you want to know exactly what browser he is using , Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
      creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        var userAgent : String  = String(ExternalInterface.call("function(){return navigator.userAgent}"));           
        trace( userAgent );
    }

]]>
</fx:Script>
```

You will get the information , For example , the above program creates the following trace

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
```

You can use this information for future !